# How to uniquely identify docker pulls by account?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have an application that collects telemetry data when run in a Docker container. The data is currently inaccurate because it counts multiple pulls and container starts from each account, rather than unique starts per account.

Is there any information my application can access or collect from the Docker image at runtime that would uniquely identify the user account that pulled and started the container?

Ideally I'd like a way to distinguish pulls and starts by individual user accounts rather than just counting total pulls and starts.

Some options I've considered:

- Environment variables set by Docker at container start
- Metadata or labels on the image
- Something available via the Docker API or CLI

But I'm not sure what would contain a user or account identifier.

Is there a standard way for a containerized application to identify the account that started it? Or any suggestions on the best approach?

Comment: Docker doesn't track the user accessing their API, just as HTTP doesn't track your local user sending the request. It's a client/server model, and there's no login to the server. This needs to be done by restricting the user to access via a higher level abstraction and not giving direct access to the API (socket).